# Contractor baseboard install. Is this caulk line standard?

Tags: flooring, painting, baseboard

Contractor is set to paint my walls tomorrow, these caulk lines I’ve been told are really large and paint alone won’t resolve the gap between the baseboard and the wall. Contractor said this would be resolved by the painters

Is this work acceptable before painting the walls? Would painters be the ones to fix this?[image]

Comment: Paint only changes the colour.  It does not fill or hide mistakes.

Comment: Looks bad. Who purchased the baseboard and what type of floor was there before?

Comment: The contractors did (or it’s suppose to be new baseboards). It was vinyl tiles to my understanding before and also after.

Answer (score 2):

Short version: no, this isn’t good work, and while it will be improved by paint, it will always look somewhat crummy.

To step back, that line exists because the baseboard dropped lower. (Flooring changes, shorter base, whatever.) If you had to have that height of baseboard, the bottom of the wall should have been prepared better (old caulk scraped off, drywall mud to smooth it).

But here’s the proverbial rub: what does your contract say? If you don’t have specific language about this, you might be out of luck.

Solution 1: get taller baseboard and cover that line.

Solution 2: have the painter scrape and mud the line, then recaulk and paint.

Solution 3: paint over it and ignore it.

Comment: Thank you. This helps a lot. The contractor has already been not the greatest and a pain to work with. All he informed me when I presented him with this photo and a ton more, is that “the painter will be taking care of all of that.” So I can ask about if they are going to have him scrape and mud the line. They’ve also been contracted to do new baseboards and some of the newly installed baseboards are either damage or look old. Hasn’t been a fun process.

Comment: If the “new” base they installed looks beaten up (not discolored — that’ll disappear with paint), then it might be an opportunity to have the contractor do-over with taller base. They’ll push back but remind them that having the painter fix that is going to cost money anyway. I don’t usually give this advice, but use your payment schedule as leverage. If all this has to be redone by someone else, you don’t want to be too far out of pocket.